# Rally - Update HTML so it filters by a date instead of release and add export button

Tags: html, rally

Can someone please help adjust this rally custom HTML so it will filter by 'c_ProductionDate' instead of release. This should be a date field. Also, can you please add a export button?

I am new to coding, and would love some resources that could point me to get to get to the answer or how you made the update as well as getting the answer. Always wanting to learn!

```
TEST REPORT

<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.1/sdk-debug.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Rally.onReady(function () {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',
launch: function() {

    this.add({
            xtype: 'rallyfieldvaluecombobox',
            itemId: 'stateComboBox',
            fieldLabel: 'Filter by Release:',
            model: 'User Story',
            field: 'Release',
            listeners: {
                select: this._onSelect,
                ready: this._onLoad,
                scope: this
            }
        });
    },

_onLoad: function() {
    this.add({
        xtype: 'rallygrid',
        columnCfgs: [
            'c_ProductionDate',
            'c_LeadTeam',
            'FormattedID',
            'Name',
            'Owner',
            'ScheduleState',
            'c_UserStoryType'
        ],
        context: this.getContext(),
        storeConfig: {
            model: 'userstory',
            filters: [this._getStateFilter()],
            fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'ScheduleState', 'c_ProductionDate', 'c_UserStoryType']
        }
    });
},

_getStateFilter: function() {
    return {
        property: 'Release',
        operator: '=',
        value: this.down('#stateComboBox').getValue()
    };
},

_onSelect: function() {
    var grid = this.down('rallygrid'),
        store = grid.getStore();

    store.clearFilter(true);
    store.filter(this._getStateFilter());
}
```

});

```
        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name:"VV",
        parentRepos:""
        });

    });
</script>



<style type="text/css">
    .app {
```

/* Add app styles here */
}

```
</style>
```

Comment: I forgot to add, c_Production date is at the User Story level

Comment: _"I forgot to add"_ - you can [edit] your questions.